# How to do asynchronous page load in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

In my Rails 4 application's home page I am displaying 3 different graphs after querying Oracle DB from my controller. The problem is that until my all 3 queries are complete my home page keeps on waiting for some time.

How can I make my queries asynchronous so that if I get the result from one query I show the first graph, if I get the result from second query I show the second graph and so on without actually blocking the entire page load ?

**home_page_controller.rb**

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @graph1_data = PaymentTransaction.find_by_sql("select * from ....")
    @graph2_data = PaymentTransaction.find_by_sql("select * from ....")
    @graph3_data = PaymentTransaction.find_by_sql("select * from ....")
  end

end
```